# Read value of a selected drop down value from speedscript/webspeed

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, webspeed

I am newbie to Webspeed/SpeedScript.

I have a drop down field on my web page (select tag of hmtl). I want the selected value of this drop down using SpeedScript/WebSpeed.

I tried "get-value()" method but this returns blank value. I went through WebSpeed API documenation (http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge102b/pdfs/aswsp/aswsp.pdf) . There are some other functions like get-field(), get-user-field(). I tried get-field() but there is no success. Please help.

HTML:

```
<form>
<select id="product" name="prd" onChange="dosmthng()">
<option> 1 </option>
<option> 2 </option>
<option> 3 </option>
</form>
```

WebSpeed/SpeedScript that I tried:

```
def variable xy as char.
xy = get-field("prd").
{&OUT} 'window.alert(' + xy + ');'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webspeed runs on the server. This means you will have to submit the values of the form for get-field function to work.

HTML:

```
<form action="your_program.p" method="get">
<select id="product" name="prd" onChange="dosmthng()">
<option> 1 </option>
<option> 2 </option>
<option> 3 </option>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

your_program.p:

```
{&OUT} get-field("prd").
```

or if you want it to alert:

```
{&OUT} '<script>' 
       alert(get-field("prd"))
       '</script>'.
```

If you want webspeed to react to the "onChange" you will have to look into some kind of AJAX-call. Not too hard but try to get the basics running first!

Comment: Thank you for the answer and also thanks for reminding that WebSpeed runs on the server.